# ClassVar for variable type defined on __init__subclass__

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, metaclass

```
class School:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.number = 0

    def test(self) -> None:
        self.number = 0


class Sophism(School):
    def test(self) -> None:
        self.number = 1


class Epicureanism(School):
    def test(self) -> None:
        self.number = 2


PhilosophySchool = TypeVar("PhilosophySchool", bound=School)


class Philosopher:
    school: ClassVar[PhilosophySchool]  # Type variable "PhilosophySchool" is unbound  [valid-type]

    def __init_subclass__(cls, /, school: type[PhilosophySchool], **kwargs: object) -> None:
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.school = school()


class Sophist(Philosopher, school=Sophism):
    pass



s1 = Sophist()  
s2 = Sophist()
s1.school.test()  # PhilosophySchool? has no attribute "test"
s1.school.number == s2.school.number == Sophist.school.number  # True  # PhilosophySchool? has no attribute "number"  
s1.school == s2.school == Sophist.school  # True  # Unsupported left operand type for == (PhilosophySchool?)
```

I am trying to make a class that automatically instantiates some properties on definition. I get multiple warnings from mypy, but I cannot understand any of them, because this code works in the interpreter.

How can I tell mypy that Philosopher's "school" variable, which I define on subclassing, is **always** a subclass of School, the very same subclass that I pass on `school=Sophism`?
In the last line, `s.school.test()`, mypy cannot even tell that school is an instance of Sophism(), not School(), and somehow it thinks it doesn't have `test` nor `number`, despite School itself having them defined.

Comment: Have you tried making `Philosopher` inherit from `Generic[PhilosophySchool]` and annotating `school` as `ClassVar[Type[PhilosophySchool]]`?

Comment: If I define `class Philosopher(Generic[PhilosophySchool]):` then mypy can't tell anything anymore, and even pylance, which normally works unlike mypy, becomes broken, so no, it doesn't work. And school is not a Type, it's a class instance shared by all instances of Philosopher.

Comment: It means that school becomes Any.

Comment: Making `Philosopher` generic, I get an error that `ClassVar` cannot contain a class variable. (It's not immediately obvious to me why that would be prohibited.)

Comment: I'm not sure you need a type variable. `school: ClassVar[School]` and `school: Type[School]` should suffice. Granted, that doesn't preclude assignments from outside `__init_subclass__` from changing the type, but it has the benefit of working.

Comment: You might also consider making the school an attribute of an *instance* of Philosopher, or making `School` a mix-in rather than the type of a class attribute.

Comment: Your suggested changes still do not let mypy find the right class of s1.school in my example. mypy still finds School, not Sophism.

Comment: School needs to be a property of the Philosopher class, not its instances, because in a real world scenario it has several very expensive methods that should only be run once per school, not once per instance, and for other various reasons, such as being accessed from classmethods.

Comment: You could define a factory function that returns a pre-made instance of the `School` subclass, rather than always creating a new instance.

Comment: But then if I have thousands of different schools, I have to import each and every single one of them every time instead of just importing the one that I need to use for my specific Philosopher declaration. And then I'd have to use importlib to selectively import, and you see how the code starts becoming quite complex for something that *should* be simple.

Comment: @chepner ClassVar cannot contain type variable for reason: type vars are bound to instances in fact, not to classes themselves. If you have `class A(Generic[_T]): foo: ClassVar[_T]`, then it's fine to have `a1: A[int]` and `a2: A[str]`. What would be `reveal_type(A.foo)` in such case - an unbound type variable? How does it relate to types of `a1.foo` and `a2.foo`? It makes little sense in general. Here the class is not generic - but metaclass is. Unfortunately, seems that `mypy` doesn't like my generic metaclass attempt

Answer (score 2):

There are a copious number of problems when trying to link a metaclass to an instance, which I believe is due to implementation immaturity of metaclass type checking. For example, unlike `typing.ClassVar`s on a class (which *are* accessible from class instances), **metaclass instance variables are not accessible from class instances** in mypy:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

class M(type):
    # *not* `ClassVar[int]`, which would definitely break at runtime
    # if accessing from the class instance later
    var: int
    def __init__(
        cls, name: str, bases: tuple[type, ...], namespace: dict[str, object]
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(name, bases, namespace)
        cls.var = 0

class C(metaclass=M):
    pass

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(C.var)  # mypy: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
    reveal_type(C().var)  # mypy: "C" has no attribute "var" [attr-defined]

>>> print(f"{C.var=}")
C.var=0
>>> print(f"{C().var=}")
C().var=0
```

---

Instead of relying on things like `__init_subclass__` or metaclass `__init__` / `__new__`, which don't (yet?) transfer type variable genericity to classes due to implementation immaturity, I would just implement a read-only [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) for `Philosopher.school` which is accessible from both the class and the instance:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing as t

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    class _schooldescriptor:
        def __init__(
            self, func: t.Callable[[Philosopher[PhilosophySchool]], PhilosophySchool], /
        ) -> None: ...
        
        # `obj: object` handles both `obj: None` (accessing descriptor from the class)
        # and `obj: Philosopher[PhilosophySchool]` (accessing descriptor from the instance).
        def __get__(
            self, obj: object, class_: type[Philosopher[PhilosophySchool]], /
        ) -> PhilosophySchool: ...

        # Do not implement `__set__` or `__delete__`; implementing
        # these would mean the descriptor is no longer read-only.
```

Define your schools of thought as usual,

```py
class School:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.number = 0

    def test(self) -> None:
        self.number = 0

class Sophism(School):
    def test(self) -> None:
        self.number = 1

class Epicureanism(School):
    def test(self) -> None:
        self.number = 2

PhilosophySchool = t.TypeVar("PhilosophySchool", bound=School)
```

Then,

1. `@_schooldescriptor` can be used to imitate a read-only class property at type-checking time;
2. [`__class_getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__class_getitem__) can be used to set the `school` instance at runtime. Despite the discouraging messages in the Python documentation, this override of `__class_getitem__` still fulfils the primary purpose of resolving generic types - it just introduces an additional functionality on top.

```py
class Philosopher(t.Generic[PhilosophySchool]):

    if t.TYPE_CHECKING:

        @_schooldescriptor
        def school(self) -> PhilosophySchool:
            ...

    else:

        def __class_getitem__(
            cls, school: type[PhilosophySchool], /
        ) -> type[Philosopher[PhilosophySchool]]:
            ConcretePhilosopher: type[
                Philosopher[PhilosophySchool]
            ] = super().__class_getitem__(school)
            ConcretePhilosopher.school = school()
            return ConcretePhilosopher
```

Choosing `__class_getitem__` as the type resolver (instead of keyword arguments to `__init_subclass__` or metaclass `__init__` / `__new__`, which don't work) then allows the following syntactic sugar and complete type-safety when accessing `school` from any concrete `Philsopher` class or subclass, or any of their instances:

```py
class Sophist(Philosopher[Sophism]):
    pass

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(Sophist.school)  # mypy: revealed type is "Sophism"
    reveal_type(Philosopher[Epicureanism].school)  # mypy: revealed type is "Epicureanism"

>>> # No typing issues in any of the following!
>>> s1 = Sophist()
>>> s2 = Sophist()
>>> s1.school.test()
>>> s1.school.number == s2.school.number == Sophist.school.number
>>> s1.school == s2.school == Sophist.school
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets you pretty close.  The sticking point seems to be that you can't use a `TypeVar` as the parameter to a `ClassVar` -- the best workaround I can think of for that is to have a `@classmethod` that casts `School` to `PhilosophySchool`.  (Sadly, `@classproperty` isn't a thing and the workarounds to *that* are really annoying so I won't try to replicate them here; having to call `school` as a method seems like the lesser evil.)

```
from typing import ClassVar, Generic, TypeVar, cast

class School:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.number = 0

    def test(self) -> None:
        self.number = 0


class Sophism(School):
    def test(self) -> None:
        self.number = 1


class Epicureanism(School):
    def test(self) -> None:
        self.number = 2


PhilosophySchool = TypeVar("PhilosophySchool", bound=School)


class Philosopher(Generic[PhilosophySchool]):
    __school: ClassVar[School]
    @classmethod
    def school(cls) -> PhilosophySchool:
        return cast(PhilosophySchool, cls.__school)

    def __init_subclass__(cls, /, school: type[PhilosophySchool], **kwargs: object) -> None:
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.__school = school()


class Sophist(Philosopher[Sophism], school=Sophism):
    pass


s1 = Sophist()  
s2 = Sophist()
s1.school().test()
assert s1.school().number == s2.school().number == Sophist.school().number
assert s1.school() == s2.school() == Sophist.school()
reveal_type(s1.school())  # revealed type is "Sophism"
```