# Can a paired hierarchy of data and metadata classes be annotated with type variables?

Tags: python, python-typing, class-hierarchy

I'm working on typing an old code base that attempts to provide uniform access to data file formats, including versions of the same format. Generally, the data format is a straightforward binary block, and the difference is in the header, so we have a structure `File(Header, Data)`.

There is a paired hierarchy, such that more recent versions of a particular format are subclasses of the previous versions of that format, as are the headers.

Here is an example hierarchy that I am trying to type annotate:

```
class MetaDataMixin:
    def __init__(self, metadata=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.metadata = {}
        if metadata:
            self.metadata.update(metadata)

class DataFile:
    def __init__(self, header=None, data=None):
        self.header = header or self.header_class()

class HeaderV1:
    magic_number = b'HDR'
    format_version = 1

class DataFileV1(DataFile):
    header_class = HeaderV1

class HeaderV2(HeaderV1, MetaDataMixin):
    format_version = 2

class DataFileV2(DataFileV1):
    header_class = HeaderV2
```

It would be nice for type checkers to be able to recognize that `DataFileV1().header` has type `HeaderV1` and `DataFileV2().header` has type `HeaderV2`. A critical component is that, for backwards compatibility, `DataFileV1` must be both an instantiable class and a superclass of `DataFileV2`.

I tried making `DataFile` generic on a `Header` variable that would annotate both the `header_class` and `header` variables. Once made concrete with `HeaderV1`, there doesn't seem to be a way to override with `HeaderV2`. Here's my attempt:

```
import typing as ty

class Header:
    pass

HdrT = ty.TypeVar('HdrT', bound=Header)    

class MetaDataMixin:
    metadata: dict[str, str]

    def __init__(self, metadata=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.metadata = {}
        if metadata:
            self.metadata.update(metadata)

class DataFile(ty.Generic[HdrT]):
    header: HdrT
    header_class: type[HdrT]
    
    def __init__(self, header: HdrT | None = None, data: ty.Any = None):
        self.header = header or self.header_class()

class HeaderV1(Header): 
    magic_number: bytes = b'HDR'
    format_version: int = 1

class DataFileV1(DataFile[HeaderV1]):
    header_class = HeaderV1

class HeaderV2(HeaderV1, MetaDataMixin):
    format_version = 2

class DataFileV2(DataFileV1, DataFile[HeaderV2]):
    header_class = HeaderV2

file1 = DataFileV1()
file2 = DataFileV2()

print(file2.header.format_version)
if ty.TYPE_CHECKING:
    # Shows HeaderV1, but I would like it to be HeaderV2
    reveal_type(file2.header)
else:
    # Acts like HeaderV2
    print(file2.header.metadata)
```

I can manually set `header: HeaderV2` in `DataFileV2`, but I'd hoped to eliminate that additional boilerplate by using type variables.

Swapping the order of the superclasses in `DataFileV2` breaks the method resolution order, so that's not an option. I had an additional thought of creating a `HdrV1T = ty.TypeVar('HdrV1T', bound=HeaderV1)` and making `class DataFileV1(DataFile[HdrV1T])`, but then the annotations of `DataFileV1` become `Any`.

---

While my question is specifically about how to retrofit typing onto an old structure, I would also be interested in how someone would design an API like this now, with typing as a first-class consideration.

Comment: `DataFile.header_class` should have type `ClassVar[type[HdrT]]` so that `mypy` knows it's a class attribute, not an instance attribute like `header`.

Comment: If this were being defined today, you probably wouldn't use a metaclass at all. You'd have a base class with an `__init_subclass__` method that defines the `metadata` class attribute for each subclass.

Comment: (Everything in `Header` seems to need `ClassVar` annotations as well. It's not entirely clear that they need to be instantiated at all, as their purposes seems to be to hold a set of constants, not model individual file headers that can differ from one file to another.)

Comment: Without knowing more about the `DataFile` subclasses, I can't comment too much, but trying to inherit from both `DataFileV1` *and* `DataFile[HeaderV2]` seems like a contradiction.

Comment: `ClassVar[type[HdrT]]` is explicitly forbidden by [PEP526](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations)

Comment: Ugh, right. So `header_class: ClassVar[Type[Header]]` would be fine, but then it's not clear how to type `header` so that it's an instance of whatever is bound to `header_class`.

Comment: For an example from our hierarchy, say DataFileV1 provides `get_data()` and looks in the header for slope and intercept parameters for scaling the raw data. HeaderV1 encodes a slope parameter while HeaderV2 provides a slope and intercept. A user that just needs to know `get_data()` is provided would check `isinstance(img, DataFileV1)`.

Other evolutions of formats include switching 16- or 32-bit fields to 32- or 64 bits while preserving the meaning, so the interface for dealing with the file doesn't change. Or a new header field is added so you need to know whether a setter method is valid.

Comment: Your solution is almost OK, especially if we had [PEP696](https://peps.python.org/pep-0696/) merged. You could create a `_DataFileV1(Generic[_T])` class where `_T = TypeVar('_T', bound=HeaderV1)`, then `class DataFileV1(_DataFileV1[HeaderV1])` and `class DataFileV2(_DataFileV1[HeaderV2])` to achieve working typing (with defaults you could have `_T` with default and avoid intermediate `_DataFileV1`). You cannot avoid the duplication in class body, unfortunately (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75336039/classvar-for-variable-type-defined-on-init-subclass))

Comment: Also you can `from typing_extensions import reveal_type` to avoid wrapping it with `if TYPE_CHECKING`.

Comment: Thanks @SUTerliakov. I think PEP696 is what I need, and until then I'll just have to annotate each class with concrete types.